# Windows forms Authentication via Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, async-await, office365, azure-active-directory

Whilst following the article [Azure Active Directory](http://www.codemag.com/article/1503041), I struggled with the following code:

```
   string authority = "https://login.windows.net/winsmartstest.onmicrosoft.com";
        string resourceURI = "https://winsmartstest.onmicrosoft.com/MyWebAPI";
        string clientID = "9329c7a4-2d61-467b-94b8-c5ce67cca6c3";
        Uri returnURI = new Uri("http://doesntreallymatter");

        AuthenticationContext authContext =
            new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        AuthenticationResult authResult =
            authContext.AcquireToken(resourceURI, clientID, returnURI);

        string authHeader = authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();

        // don't do this in prod
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            ((s, c, c2, se) => true);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request =
            new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:44300/api/tasks");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(responseString);
```

I get the following error:

> Error 1   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
>   c:\users\6025\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\webapi.test\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs   43  28  WindowsFormsApplication1

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward. You need to change your method to `async`.

Comment: Can you post the code of your entire method including method signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Azure AD. It's that you're using `await` without being in an `async` method. You can change the method to `async`, or, remove `await`. If you remove `await`, you need to call the `Result` property of the tasks that will be returned. Removing `await` is probably the simplest way to get your code working, but not the best for performance.

Like `var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;`

Here is more information on async and await: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: `Removing await is probably the simplest way to get your code working` --> I don't think this would solve the problem as the method being called (`ReadAsStringAsync`) is async. If you don't await this method, you may not get desired result.

Comment: The Async method will return a Task. The Task has a Result property which contains the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the trouble async had to be added in the event
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}